# How much freight could the Millennium Falcon carry or pull?

Tags: star-wars

Something that has puzzled me since I saw the original film in the cinema was in what way would the Falcon be used as a freighter? It is described as such, but where would the freight go?

You could only get a few cubic meters of storage in there. I have looked at the models and schematics and remain unconvinced that it would make a viable freighter.

Alternatively, did it pull or push cargo units similar to how a tractor unit pulls its trailer in an articulated lorry?

Comment: Quality vs. Quantity of freight ? maybe "spice" was very profitable cargo!

Comment: It's a pusher, similar to buses of the same name that have their engines in the rear. There are articulated pushers but by definition no semi-tractor-trailer is ever a pusher.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the excellent (albeit not especially canon) [*Millennium Falcon Haynes Workshop Owner's Manual*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345533046), the unmodified Millennium Falcon [YT-1300 Corellian Light Freighter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/YT-1300_light_freighter) can hold approximately 25 metric tons of cargo in its primary (and two secondary) holds.

[image: YT-1300 Freighter specification block, noting a cargo capacity of "25 metric tons"]

[image: YT-1300 freighter cutaway diagram with the main hold and 2 additional holds indicated]

In full cargo-lifter configuration, it can be modified with additional pods and engines allowing over 100 Metric Tons to be carried safely.

For the record, this is what 25 tonnes of sand looks like;

[image: Photograph, looking down from above and behind, of an articulated tipper lorry (semi-trailer dump truck) full of sand]

Comment: Great answer. My concern is where you put that volume. What're is there space for even 25m2 or even 100 m2.

Comment: @KevinColyer - The main hold appears to be at least 8m X 20M. The secondary holds appear to be at least 6m x 6m (each). That kind of space could easily accommodate 25 tons of boxed cargo

Comment: @KevinColyer - IF you have it in "cargo" configuration, it has bolt-on pods that sit above the saucer...

Comment: square (or cubic for volume) metreage is not the same as tonnage - you could have small, dense cargo that occupies a small volume.

Comment: @HorusKol - True, If we're talking metals (like gold bullion, for example), it would only be about two palettes worth; http://demonocracy.info/infographics/world/gold/images/demonocracy-gold-10_tons-100_tons.jpg

Comment: Why would they transport sand? Surely there are more lucrative commodities in Kessel than that?

Comment: @WOPR - I was using sand as an example of a typical heavy freight item.

Comment: It's explicitly a light-freighter though, and that makes sense when you consider what he's shipped in-canon.  Expensive and rare spices, and passengers.  It doesn't carry much, but it gets what you want to move moved faster than anything else.  Also, I'm going to have to assume that "tonnage" refers to the amount of excess weight it can carry for successful takeoff, otherwise that metric makes no sense.

Comment: @Zibbobz - I agree. It's definitely not a cargo *transporter*. It's more like a fast picket that happens to have quite a big hold. The "metric" simply refers to it being an American tonne (1000Kg), not an Imperial ton (1016Kg).

Comment: @Richard Ah, so it IS mass and not weight. Very well.

Answer (score -1):

It was a tug.
It would latch on to external containers in addition to internal storage.
Its cargo was limitless.
That's what the front mandibles are for.

Comment: can you provide proofs?

Comment: I have seen it in [an answer about the Falcon cockpit position](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/127446/40711), though it comes from a TFA-related book, and it could be seen as somewhat of a retconning.